# unable to insert new info to existing contacts on android 2.2.1 froyo

Tags: android, contacts

I used below code to insert a new info to a existing contacts, it's run on emulator 2.2, 2.3.3, and android gingbear but can't run on android 2.2.1 froyo.

here my code

```
if(updContact_textMail.getText().toString().length() != 0)
            {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, strId)
                    .withValue(Email.DATA1, updContact_textMail.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(Email.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());
            }
```

default save account contacts to phone for froyo is "vnd.sec.contact.phone" for accoutname and acounttype.
default save account contacts to phone for other ( emulator 2.2, gingbear 2.3.4...) is null for account name, account type.
What's diffrerent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Samsung SmartPhone?
vnd.sec.contact.phone is default user account using Samsung smartphones.
Samsung smartphone has two Contact type; one is Samsung default phonebook ans the other is Google account.
vnd.sec.contact.phone means 'the contacts contains Samsung default phonebook'.
And I guess the device vendor(Samsung) customize the Contacts Applications.
that'sthe reason thar the code do not run.
HTH.

Comment: yes I use Samsung Galaxy Fit :(, how to fix my proplem with samsung phone :|